# why i cant move android app buttons in visual studio with mouse ? in android studio its possible

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, button

When I want to move my button with mouse I can't in Visual Studio but in Android Studio it is possible.

Can someone help me to move my buttons with mouse in Visual Studio? I'm using relative layout and still the button can't move.

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin does not support rearrange controls from the designer like android studio.
You have to do that from Xaml code. Try to understand how layouts works on android.
This link will be helpful while explains how to design your GUI using layouts Horizontally, vertically and relative layouts.

[Using the Android Designer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/android-designer/designer-walkthrough?tabs=vswin)

So mainly, you have to divide your GUI with layouts and arrange the controls inside. Not moving them to a specific location by mouse.
In addition to that, it's a good practice to learn [Dealing with sizes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05) which will show how to use Pixels, points, dps, DIPs, and DIUs for better arranging using margin and padding. And weight attribute is really helpful when arranging the controls